# Phalcon framework Assets manager : "/index.php" is always prepended in the assets path when ouput

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm new to phalcon framework but it seems great!

Recently I decided to use assets manager in my project but an issue occurred.
when I try to output the added assets, it prints the path with '**/index.php**' prepended...

I put this code into controller's indexAction:

```
$this->assets
   ->collection("commonJs")
   ->addJs('js/draggable.js')
   ->addJs('js/common.js')
   ->addFilter( new Phalcon\Assets\Filters\Jsmin()  );

$this->assets
    ->collection('commonCss')
    ->addCss('css/material-icons.css',true,false)
    ->addcss('css/common.css',true,true)
    ->addFilter(new Phalcon\Assets\Filters\Cssmin());
```

and use this inside volt to ouput the assets:

```
 <head>
 ....
 {{ assets.outputJs('commonJs')}}
 </head>
 <body>
 ...
 {{ assets.outputJs('commoCss')}}
 </body>
```

but the printed output seems a little wierd:

I think it should prints the path like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'  href='css/common.css'>
```

or

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/common.js'>
```

but it actually outputs like this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'  href='/index.phpcss/common.css'> 
..
 <script type='text/javascript' src='/index.phpjs/common.js'>
```

or if i set the path in the addJs like '/js/...' instead of 'js/...'
then output is :

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='/index.php/js/...'>
```

I'm new to phalcon and I don't know what I'm doing wrong and how to remove prepended index.php in the output path.

**Could someone please help me on this?**

FYI, I'm using nginx with php7.1 & fpm and my nginx-site.conf is like below, which is almost same as phalcon documentation :

```
server {
         listen       80;
         root /var/www2/public;
         index index.html index.htm index.php;

         # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
         server_name tpnew.dev;

     error_log  /usr/local/var/log/nginx/newtp.error.log; #debug;
     log_not_found off;


     location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;
     #   try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
     }

 location ~ \.php$ {
     try_files      $uri = 404;
     fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000; # php71
     fastcgi_index  /index.php;
     fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     include        fastcgi_params;

     fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
     fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
     fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
     fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
 }
     location ~ /\.ht {
         deny all;
     }

 }
```

Comment: Found out the resolution. I had to remove or edit baseUri in the config.php file which is generated automatically by phalcon dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well, and instead of tinkering with the webserver config, I edited the config.php baseUri entry like this:

Before:

```
'baseUri' => preg_replace('/public([\/\\\\])index.php$/', '', $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]),
```

After:

```
'baseUri' => preg_replace(['/public([\/\\\\])index.php$/', '@/index.php@i'], '', $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]),
```

so basically just making sure, a single /index.php is stripped from the PHP_SELF field as well

Answer (score 0):

In yout Nginx configuration, try to change this line `fastcgi_index /index.php;` to `fastcgi_index /;`.

Answer (score 0):

To remove index.php from generated URL, change `baseUri` on `config.php`.

Old: `'baseUri'        => preg_replace('/public([\/\\\\])index.php$/', '', $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]),`

New: `'baseUri' => preg_replace(['/public([\/\\\\])index.php$/', '@/index.php@i'], '/', $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]),`

> **[radonthetyrant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2982373/radonthetyrant)** already mentioned similar answer, but that generating *projectnamecontroller* URL.  But I need *project/controller*.  So I changed to this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
$headerJs = $this->assets->collection('headerJs')->setPrefix('/')->setLocal(false);
    .....

    $headerJs->addJs('js/library/jquery.min.js');
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more context to explain to the OP why this is a good answer?